# Compare Multiple Columns in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a requirement like this below:

Suppose I have more than 2 columns in Excel (let say 3: A, B , C). Now I need to check the common values among 3 columns. Means, the values of A should be in B and C, values of B should be in A and C, values of C should be in B and A.

Comparing the two columns can be done using below formula:

`NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,$B:$B,1,FALSE)))`.

If the value of A is present in B, the result is `TRUE`, else `FALSE`

But how to do the same for multiple columns? Please guide

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`AND()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/and-function-HP010069828.aspx) function. Should look something like

`AND( NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,$B:$B,1,FALSE))) , NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,$C:$C,1,FALSE))) )`

then. (Maybe note the commutative and transitive properties of the logical "and": X && Y <==> Y && X and (X && Y) && (Y && Z) ==> X && Z)

Of course, this only does the lookup for A1. If you need the full intersection of all three columns there should be another solution for that.

Comment: Thank you for this help.
What could be the formulae for the Full Intersection of 3 columns (multiple columns at a time)?